# better ways to combine two array items into one string

Tags: c#

Hello Please could you suggest better ways of writing this C# code.

Basically when NumberList has missing values between '-' I am trying to rebuild the String with default Values. 
The final result should be "123-10-45-9-09"

As you can see value of "second-10" is replaced as the second item in the string.

10, 9 and 09 are filled in from the value string values.

This is the bad string which is missing some values.
  string NumberList = "123--45--";

I have stored this string value in my app.config file.
  string valuestring = "first-12,second-10,third-99,fourth-9,fifth-09";

```
protected string MissingNumberString(string Number)
{
      string NumberList = "123--45--";
      string valuestring = "first-12,second-10,third-99,fourth-9,fifth-09";
      var companyAccountList = valuestring.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      var result = NumberList.Split('-');
      int counter = 0;

      var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
      foreach (string s in companyAccountList)
      {
           string t = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('-') + 1);

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result[counter]))
               builder.Append(t).Append("-");
           else
           {
               if (companyAccountList.Length == counter)
                   builder.Append(result[counter]);
               else
                   builder.Append(result[counter]).Append("-");
           }
           counter++;
       }
       return builder.ToString();           
}
```

Comment: You may have better luck asking this type of question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

One way (assuming valuestring is in order and do not miss any defaults) to achieve this would be

```
string MissingNumber(string Number)
{
    string valuestring = "first-12,second-10,third-99,fourth-9,fifth-09";
    var regex = Regex.Matches(valuestring,@"(?<=-)(\d*)(?<=,)?");
    var defaults = regex.Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
    var newArray = Number.Split('-').Select((x,index)=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)?defaults[index]:x);
    return string.Join("-",newArray);
}
```

The code uses Regular Expression to break the ValueString and read the default values.

```
Regex.Matches(valuestring,@"(?<=-)(\d*)(?<=,)?");
```

The regular expression uses non-capturing groups to capture a number which is prefixed as by an optional "-" character and suffixed by an optional "," character.

Once the defaults are parsed into a List (assuming that the positions are in  order and do not miss any values), we loop through the input string (which has been split based on delimiter), check if it is Empty, and if so, use the value from the Defaults (based on our assumption, it should have same index).

**Update**
Based on the comments, it looks like you other data in the original string, and hence the concerned sub-string has to be captured first.

We could update the Missing Number method as

```
static string MissingNumber(string Number)
{
    string valuestring = "first-12,second-10,third-99,fourth-9,fifth-09";
    var regexDefaultValues = Regex.Matches(valuestring,@"(?<=-)(\d*)(?<=,)?");
    var defaults = regexDefaultValues.Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
        
    var regexNumberToParse = new Regex(@"(\d)*-(\d)*-(\d)*-(\d)*-(\d)*");
    var capturedNumberFormat = regexNumberToParse.Match(Number).Value;
    var newArray = capturedNumberFormat.Split('-').Select((x,index)=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)?defaults[index]:x);
    var ValueWithDefaults = string.Join("-",newArray);
    return regexNumberToParse.Replace(Number,ValueWithDefaults);
}
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tfxYVg)

Comment: Thank you very much that was helpful. One quick question. What does this line do? var regex = Regex.Matches(valuestring,@"(?<=-)(\d*)(?<=,)?");

Comment: @user1987750 my apologies, should have added some description. I have added few now, please check it.

Comment: thank you very much Anu viswan. yes the positions are in order and do not miss any values.

Comment: What if my string is value is ",CHEK,10/28/2019,123--45--,'2220289,'0001028,\"010003 - 0011008 - JOY TO G - 3 day m p\",15.00,,,10/25/2019,"   I need to replace same default values within this string only for value "123--45--"  The output string should be ",CHEK,10/28/2019,123-10-45-9-09,'2220289,'0001028,\"010003 - 0011008 - JOY TO G - 3 day m p\",15.00,,,10/25/2019,"

Comment: In your demo Code  Console.WriteLine(MissingNumber(",CHEK,10/28/2019,123--45--,'2220289,'0001028,\"010003 - 0011008 - JOY TO G - 3 day m p\",15.00,,,10/25/2019,"));   /* output is showing ,CHEK,10/28/2019,123-10-45-9-,'2220289,'0001028,"010003 - 0011008 - JOY TO G - 3 day m p",15.00,,,10/25/2019,   which is missing the last default value 09

Comment: @user1987750 I see that you have other information in the original string. So the "concerned substring" has to be parsed out before we apply our logic. I have updated the answer and demo code. Kindly verify